# Finding login password parameter names for JMeter

Tags: performance, http, authentication, web, jmeter

This might sound trivial but how do you find the names of the log in parameters?

I am trying to teach myself how to use JMeter and write a script that logs into say...www.amazon.com (just an example). In the HTTP Request how do I know the names I need to add (i.e. in the attached image how do I know the parameter names were username (not usr or user etc...) and password (not pass or pswrd etc...) [image: JMeter HHTP Request]

Comment: Look at HTML source or (better) do Inspect Element in Chrome or Firebug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Andrey Botalov said in the comments, look at HTML source or (better) do Inspect Element in Chrome or Firebug.